# Grub freezes on the selection menu, after video card swap

Tags: ubuntu, video, grub, freeze, crash

A while back I removed my nvidia video card and at restart grub freezed immediately in the selection menu. Even after placing the video card back, it continued to freeze. Which is strange since no memory ought to have changed.

At the time I just reinstalled ubuntu 10.10, but now I removed the video card again. The same happened, even after placing the card back. I'm completely lost here, as to what is going on.

Clues?
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You may have something in your grub.conf that doesn't like your new video mode.  You can try to put the old video card back to be sure (if possible).
If this is not the issue, you may have an issue with grub.conf that just cooincided with your video card, but in reality had nothing to do with it.
Try this out: HOWTO: Purge and Reinstall Grub 2 from Live CD: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1581099